# How to make a success ulr for my contact page

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I want the client to be redirected to another HTML page as a successfully sent message in my contact form. But I don't know exactly what is wrong here. I can't redirect to my success page but the form works.
#my main app's url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('^contact/', include('contactus.urls')),
]
```

#my contact app url.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .views import ContactUsView

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', ContactUsView.as_view(), {}, 'contactus'),
url(r'^success/$', TemplateView.as_view(),
    {}, 'contactus-success'),
]
```

#contact app view.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from contactus.forms import ContactUsForm


class ContactUsView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contactus/contact.html'
    email_template_name = 'contactus/contact_notification_email.txt'
    form_class = ContactUsForm
    success_url = "/contact/success/"
    subject = "Contact Us Request"

def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(ContactUsView, self).get_initial()
    if not self.request.user.is_anonymous:
        initial['name'] = self.request.user.get_full_name()
        initial['email'] = self.request.user.email

    return initial

   def form_valid(self, form):
        form_data = form.cleaned_data

    if not self.request.user.is_anonymous:
        form_data['username'] = self.request.user.username

    # POST to the support email
    sender = settings.SERVER_EMAIL
    recipients = (getattr(settings, 'CONTACT_US_EMAIL'),)

    reply_to = form_data.get('email') or sender

    tmpl = loader.get_template(self.email_template_name)
    email = EmailMessage(
        self.subject,
        tmpl.render(form_data),
        sender,
        recipients,
        reply_to=[reply_to],
    )
    email.send()

    return super(ContactUsView, self).form_valid(form)
```

#contact app forms.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django import forms


class ContactUsForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=512)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=512)
    description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': "form-control"}),
        required=True)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ContactUsForm, self).clean()

    return cleaned_data
```

#Contact.html

```
{% extends 'website/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block main %}

<!-- ======= Breadcrumbs ======= -->
<section id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ol>
    </div>

  </div>
  </section><!-- End Breadcrumbs -->


 <section id="contact" class="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="col-lg-10">
    <form action="." method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">{% csrf_token %}
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group {% if form.name.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"
                   data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars"
                       id="id_name" placeholder="Your Name"
                       value="{% if form.data.name %}{{form.data.name}}{% else%}                                 {{form.initial.name}}{% endif %}" />                                                
                     <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0 {% if form.email.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email"
                       id="email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email"
                       id="id_email" placeholder="Your Email"
                       value="{% if form.data.email %}{{form.data.email}}{% else     %}{{form.initial.email}}{% endif %}" />
                <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
         <div class="form-group mt-3 {% if form.subject.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject"     placeholder="Subject"
                           data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject"      />
           <div class="validate"></div>
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
           <div class="form-group mt-3 {% if form.description.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
               <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="5" data-rule="required"
                         data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send         Message</button></div>
    
    </form>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section><!-- End Contact Section -->
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error could be from the view.

try:

```
success_url = "/success/"
```

or you could leave your view like that and change the url in urls.py to:

```
url(r'^contact/success/$',......),
```